# ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

I used `create-next-app` to create my next.js project boiler plate. But as soon i run `npm run dev` i get the error:

```
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration[0].node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration[0].node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration[0].node has an unknown property 'devServer'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
 - configuration[1].node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration[1].node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration[1].node has an unknown property 'devServer'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    at validate (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\schema-utils3\index.js:1:153657)
    at validateSchema (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:137945:2)
    at create (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:141384:24)
    at webpack (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:141426:32)
    at f (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:98978:16)
    at HotReloader.start (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\server\hot-reloader.js:18:415)
    at async DevServer.prepare (C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js:16:453)
    at async C:\Users\crisp\OneDrive\Documents\Next.js\next-startup\nextflix\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:22:1 {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'anyOf',
      dataPath: '[0].node',
      schemaPath: '#/anyOf',
      params: {},
      message: 'should match some schema in anyOf',
      schema: [Array],
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Object],
      children: [Array]
.....
```

My `next.config.js` looks as follows.

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty'
    }
    return config
  }
};
```

Nothing has changed yet. This is the default. May you please explain to me why am i getting this error.

Any help input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `JDB`'s answer i had a clear hint. I configured my `next.js` app to use `webpack4` after reading [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5). Here is my new `next.cofig.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack5: false,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.node = {
      dns: "mock",
      fs: "empty",
      path: true,
      url: false,
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Can you check any of the dependecies on Nextjs 11 need to be updated.
In my case updating `next-transpile-modules` to Version: `^8.0.0` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You are running webpack 5, [which only supports](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/) `__dirname`, `__filename` and `global`.

Your config assumes webpack 4, which supports many more properties [including Node core libraries](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries).

You need to pick which version of webpack you want to run and make sure that your config matches.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it gaves me a clear hint. But i couldn't find a way way to configure webpack 5 if you can please post the `next.config.js` that works with webpack 5.

Answer (score 4):

[Next.js has now `webpack-5` enabled by default.](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5)

If you don't wanna switch back to `webpack-4` (for [obvious reasons](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#general-direction)), your configuration should look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
    return config;
  }
};
```

I saw the answer you posted, there you are configuring `path` and `url` also. But you actually don't need to manually configure them as Next.js handles it for you.

For `dns`, you may do something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      const fallback = config.resolve.fallback;
      fallback.fs = false;

      fallback.dns = function () {
        if (!arguments.length) return;
        const callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback(null, '0.0.0.0');
      };
      // or after installing `node-libs-browser`
      // fallback.dns = require.resolve('node-libs-browser/dns');
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

**Refs:**

- [To v5 from v4 | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/)
- [Automatic Node.js Polyfills Removed](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#automatic-nodejs-polyfills-removed)
- [`resolve.fallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback)
- [next/build/webpack-config.ts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/88ed5269b5e0c76667780f4823b669c392bc6713/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L445-L468)
- [Webpack 5 Adoption](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23498)

Comment: It didn't work. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just update the Node version. I was receiving this error also when I tried to create a new next.js app.  I had node version 14.16 installed but it seems Next needs ^14.17.0.  After updating to 14.18.0 I created a new next app and it ran fine with the default next.config file.